# Android action buttons in action bar not appearing?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, action-menu

I want to create an add button in the action bar but it doesn't seem to appear when i run thee code.

Here is my **main_activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_add) {

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

This is my **main_activity_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
          android:title="Add"
          android:showAsAction="always"
           />

</menu>
```

Please Help
I cant figure out what's wrong !

Comment: does it appear in the overflow menu?

Comment: Nop. the 3 dots dots of the overflow menu also didn't show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Activity extends ActionBarActivity you would be using AppCompat from support library.

So change to

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
      android:title="Add"
      yourapp:showAsAction="always"
       />
    ...
</menu>
```

Quoting docs

> Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace
>   defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML
>   attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do
>   not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use
>   your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the
>   support library.

Comment: its fine. after adding the namespace it works fine .

Answer (score 0):

Change your menu_xml to this :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="action_location_found">
</menu>
```

Comment: Why?
Where u getting the prob?
Its running fine on ma side

Comment: @user3243147 this does not change anything. this is almost same as what op posted

Answer (score 0):

Replace your menu file with below menu file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="yourpackagename.Mainactivity" >



<item android:id="@+id/action_add" 
  android:icon="@drawable/add_plush" app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

thats it...